# How can I turn the values of a nested dict into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dictionary:

```
{'United States Treasury Bonds 2.5%': {'Assets_%': 4.97,
  'Name': 'United States Treasury Bonds 2.5%'},
 'United States Treasury Bonds 2.88%': {'Assets_%': 6.33,
  'Name': 'United States Treasury Bonds 2.88%'},
 'United States Treasury Bonds 3%': {'Assets_%': 4.24,
  'Name': 'United States Treasury Bonds 3%'},
 'United States Treasury Bonds 3.13%': {'Assets_%': 5.75,
  'Name': 'United States Treasury Bonds 3.13%'},
 'United States Treasury Bonds 4.25%': {'Assets_%': 3.8599998,
  'Name': 'United States Treasury Bonds 4.25%'}}
```

I'd like to get Name & Assets into a DF.

I tried `s = pd.DataFrame(DataDict)` but it looks like this:

```
    United States Treasury Bonds 2.88%  United States Treasury Bonds 3.13%  United States Treasury Bonds 2.5%   United States Treasury Bonds 3% United States Treasury Bonds 4.25%
Name    United States Treasury Bonds 2.88%  United States Treasury Bonds 3.13%  United States Treasury Bonds 2.5%   United States Treasury Bonds 3% United States Treasury Bonds 4.25%
Assets_%    6.33    5.75    4.97    4.24    3.86
```

I thought of transposing(adding `.transpose()` )  it but which kind of works but then I have a ugly index(which isn't going to be unique as more dicts get added).

```
    Name    Assets_%
United States Treasury Bonds 2.88%  United States Treasury Bonds 2.88%  6.33
United States Treasury Bonds 3.13%  United States Treasury Bonds 3.13%  5.75
United States Treasury Bonds 2.5%   United States Treasury Bonds 2.5%   4.97
United States Treasury Bonds 3% United States Treasury Bonds 3% 4.24
United States Treasury Bonds 4.25%  United States Treasury Bonds 4.25%  3.86
```

What can I do to just get the value in of the nested dict as a DF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to get Name & Assets into a DF.

see below

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'United States Treasury Bonds 2.5%': {'Assets_%': 4.97,
                                              'Name': 'United States Treasury Bonds 2.5%'},
        'United States Treasury Bonds 2.88%': {'Assets_%': 6.33,
                                               'Name': 'United States Treasury Bonds 2.88%'},
        'United States Treasury Bonds 3%': {'Assets_%': 4.24,
                                            'Name': 'United States Treasury Bonds 3%'},
        'United States Treasury Bonds 3.13%': {'Assets_%': 5.75,
                                               'Name': 'United States Treasury Bonds 3.13%'},
        'United States Treasury Bonds 4.25%': {'Assets_%': 3.8599998,
                                               'Name': 'United States Treasury Bonds 4.25%'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data.values())
print(df)
```

output

```
   Assets_%                                Name
0      4.97   United States Treasury Bonds 2.5%
1      6.33  United States Treasury Bonds 2.88%
2      4.24     United States Treasury Bonds 3%
3      5.75  United States Treasury Bonds 3.13%
4      3.86  United States Treasury Bonds 4.25%
```

Comment: @Lostsoul I am glad I managed to help. Feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`

```
out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,'index')
                                    Assets_%                                Name
United States Treasury Bonds 2.5%       4.97   United States Treasury Bonds 2.5%
United States Treasury Bonds 2.88%      6.33  United States Treasury Bonds 2.88%
United States Treasury Bonds 3%         4.24     United States Treasury Bonds 3%
United States Treasury Bonds 3.13%      5.75  United States Treasury Bonds 3.13%
United States Treasury Bonds 4.25%      3.86  United States Treasury Bonds 4.25%
```